# TemplateSyntaxError at /comments/10/ Could not parse the remainder: '==comm.user.id' from 'request.user.id==comm.user.id'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

After using for loop I get a specific comment and its related user and only want to delete the comment if that user has written it. How to write variable inside {% if ---%}.

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\socialnetwork\socialapp\templates\socialapp\comment.html, error at line 27
   Could not parse the remainder: '==comm.user.id' from 'request.user.id==comm.user.id'
   17 :             <P>Please <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> to add comment </P>
   18 : 
   19 :             {% endif %}
   20 :         </form>
   21 :         <h3>comments..</h3>
   22 : 
   23 :         {% for comm in comments %}
   24 : 
   25 :         <a class="comment-user" href="{% url 'profile' comm.user.username %}">{{comm.user}}</a>
   26 :         {{comm.comment}}
   27 :          {% if request.user.id==comm.user.id %} 
   28 :         <a class="delete" href="/delete_comment/{{post.id}}/{{comm.id}}/">Delete</a>
   29 :         {% endif %}
   30 :         <br><br>
   31 :         {% endfor %}
   32 :         <!--{{post}} {{comm.id}}-->
   33 : 
   34 :     </div>
   35 : </div>
   36 : {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use a variable is to use the `with` tag. Example:

```html
{% with name="World" %}     
<html>
<div>Hello {{name}}!</div>
</html>
{% endwith %}
```

However this may not be possible in your case. I would rather recommend having a custom property on the comment sent as part of the request, such that you can use `comm.can_delete` to check if the user can delete the comment. Add the `can_delete` property to your backend where you set it's value to be `request.user.id == comm.user.id` as you need.

I don't know how your backend looks, so I can't tell you how to do it, but hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are missing some spaces?

```
{% if request.user.id == comm.user.id %}
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked,but i want to know the logic behind it .